# Class in c# which gives the information about the machine

Tags: c#

I want to get the information about the the machine configuration i.e like ip address of the machine

Comment: Please clarify what kind of information dou you need? Hardware, Windows user info, network, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dns Class

I think the below link will help you in the above context

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx

Answer (score 6):

you may use [Dns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8hth2dy(v=VS.80).aspx) for ip/host information  and 
[Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) for generic system information (os, version)

Answer (score 3):

For general machine information, you'll want to use WMI.  It is supported by the classes in the System.Management namespace, in particular the ManagementQuery class.

The best way to get started on this is the [WmiCodeCreator utility](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en).  It lets you discover what WMI classes are available on the machine and run queries.  Best of all, it auto-generates the C# code you need, ready to cut-and-paste into your program.  Strongly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [**Sytem.Environment**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx), too, though it will not tell your the ip address. But you can find:

- MachineName
- UserName
- OSVersion
- ...

For an IP look at the [**Dns**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns_members.aspx)-class, as *klausbyskov* or *Andrey* suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment_properties%28VS.71%29.aspx) class will get some detail about the machine name, logged on user etc. You can use get the IP Address from that:

```
 System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(Environment.MachineName);
```

Or just use:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`Dns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns_members.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses("localhost");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Net.Dns` to get out stuff like hostname and IP Address(es). But you might need to use other classes for other information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx

Comment: No such class. It's System.Net.Dns.